# Create Reload Button with Path Markup Geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, path, geometry, markup

I want to create a reload icon using wpf path markup syntax. The icon shall look like this:

[image]

The problem is that i dont know how to create an open circle properly with for example Elliptical Arcs.

A similar button i already created is the following. My reload button shall be in the same scale.

```
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="buttonCustomDelete">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Path">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Style>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

        <Canvas >
            <Path x:Name="circle">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="7,7" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7"/>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
            <Path x:Name="cross">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="3,3" EndPoint="11,11"/>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="11,3" EndPoint="3,11"/>
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>

        </Canvas>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="cross" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                <Setter TargetName="circle" Property="Fill" Value="#DB4437"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="cross" Property="Stroke" Value="LightGray"/>
                <Setter TargetName="circle" Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I would use the [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and then just export the drawing as xaml. Sorted

Comment: U can use IncScape and let this programm draw your `XAML`-`Paths` http://blog.tiaan.com/link/2009/02/21/vectorize-bitmaps-to-xaml-using-potrace-inkscape

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer!

Answer (score 2):

As allready mentioned - you can use `Inkscape` to let the programm draw your `Path` - check Tutorial [here](http://blog.tiaan.com/link/2009/02/21/vectorize-bitmaps-to-xaml-using-potrace-inkscape)

If you feel ok with third party librarys - I would recommend you [Font Awesome for WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome.WPF/)

It is a pretty sick `NuGet` `package` and includes Reload `Icon` like showed in your question. It also has pretty much downloads - so don't fear to use it. It also has a [MIT](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE) license - what is pretty cool.

You can also check out their [Repository](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF/blob/master/LICENSE) - it is open source.

**Additional Information:** How to use `Path` in a `Button`:

```
    <Button Height="55"
            Width="55">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="35"
                           Height="35">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                     Visual="{StaticResource my_fontawesome_icon}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
```

Please don't forget to add ressources. You can also just paste the path into the `VisualBrush.Visual`.

Comment: FontAwesome sounds good to me. I just dont get it how i can use the icon itself as a button. i dont want to put the icon on the standard button.

Comment: Update with an example !

Comment: Does not work for me because i dont know how to set the static resource. I also want to recognize when my icon is hovered and change the color. I usually did this with triggers (see my initial post) but it seems to work different with fontawesome.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an aged topic, but one may try something like:

```
              <Path Stroke="DarkGreen"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                Data="M14,6 A6,6 0 1 0 16,10 M14,5 L9,2 M14,5 L9,8 "
                Height="20"
                Width="20" />
```

It's not the form, OP requested, but should be give a hint for 'open circle'.